# Get unique element from second list

Tags: c#, linq

From two lists `existAccount` and `newAccounts`:

```
List<string> existAccount = new List<string>() 
{ 
    "123123123123123123", 
    "111111111111111111", 
    "555555555555555555" 
};
List<Acc> newAccounts = new List<Acc>() 
{
    new Acc{Number="111111111111111111", SubId = 5},
    new Acc{Number="123123123123123123", SubId = 9},
    new Acc{Number="333333333333333333", SubId = 7},
    new Acc{Number="444444444444444444", SubId = 2}
};
```

I want to get only this `Acc` elements where `acc.Number` doesn't exist in first list. So output should be:

```
new Acc{Number="333333333333333333", SubId = 7},
new Acc{Number="444444444444444444", SubId = 2}
```

I was trying `var result = newAccounts.Select(a => a.Number).Except(existAccounts)` but in this case i don't get `SubId`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var result = newAccounts.Where(x => !existAccount.Contains(x.Number)).ToList()
```

This will give you all `Acc` objects which `Number`'s are not present in `existAccount`.